# Android - Listview Wrong Position Getview

Tags: android, json, listview

I have Json data and bind listview.It's ok.
When I click on the button in the row, the textbox on the wrong line is being updated.

My adapter codes.Thank you all in advance.

Hi guys,

I have Json data and bind listview.It's ok.
When I click on the button in the row, the textbox on the wrong line is being updated.

My adapter codes.Thank you all in advance.

```
public class UrunAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Urunler> {

ArrayList<Urunler> urunlist;
private static LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;
private Context context;
public ArrayList<UrunlerSecilen> secilenUrunler=new ArrayList<UrunlerSecilen>();;


public UrunAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Urunler> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    urunlist = objects;
    this.context = context;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        //setting up the Views
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    holder.tvUrunAdi=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUrunAdi);




    holder.tvFiyat=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFiyat);

    holder.imgUrunFoto=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgUrunFoto);

    holder.btnArttir=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnArttir);

    holder.btnEksilt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEksilt);


    final EditText edtAdet=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtAdet);



    holder.btnArttir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String strAdetVal=edtAdet.getText().toString();


            int adetValue=Integer.parseInt(strAdetVal);



            if (adetValue>=20)
            {

                adetValue=20;
            }

            else
            {
                adetValue=adetValue+1;
            }
            edtAdet.setText(Integer.toString(adetValue));


        }
    });



    holder.btnEksilt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String strAdetVal=edtAdet.getText().toString();


            int adetValue=Integer.parseInt(strAdetVal);



            if (adetValue<=0)
            {

                adetValue=0;
            }

            else
            {
                adetValue=adetValue-1;
            }

            edtAdet.setText(Integer.toString(adetValue));


        }
    });





    holder.tvUrunAdi.setText(urunlist.get(position).getUrunAdi());


    Picasso.with(context).load(urunlist.get(position).getFoto()).fit().into(holder.imgUrunFoto);



    holder.tvFiyat.setText(urunlist.get(position).getFiyat());




    return convertView;

}


static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvUrunAdi;
    public TextView tvFiyat;
    public ImageView imgUrunFoto;
    public EditText edtAdet;
    public TextView btnArttir;
    public TextView btnEksilt;
    public TextView btnEkle;
    public TextView lblAdet;
    public TextView tvUrunId;



}


private static class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


    ImageView bmImage;


    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {



        this.bmImage = bmImage;




    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this following code:

Register your `Edittext` in `ViewHolder` class then
Change your code onclick of button as below

`String strAdetVal=edtAdet.getText().toString();`

Instance of use this

```
String strAdetVal=holder.edtAdet.getText().toString();
```

I hope this may help you

Comment: I am clicking button in listview row.For example i pressed first row.First row and last row button background change.I clicked second button.Second button and previous button color change.

Comment: I am looking index on log cat.Row indexes is true

Comment: @Developer007 i am not getting what is your problem...can you explain more clearly what you want.

Comment: I click on a button in the listview but it acts like I'm pushing more than one button. When I press the first row button, both the first line and the last line are being processed.